# TableViewer's EditingSupport with String input

Tags: java, swt, jface, editing, tableviewer

I use a `TableViewer` to display comma separated `String`s. The implementation looks like this:

```
TableViewer tblvwrGroupAssignments = new TableViewer(container, SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
Table tblGroupAssignments = tblvwrGroupAssignments.getTable();
tblGroupAssignments.setLinesVisible(true);
tblGroupAssignments.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, true, 1, 2));
final TableViewerColumn clmnGroupAssignments = new TableViewerColumn(tblvwrGroupAssignments, SWT.NONE);
tblGroupAssignments.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event)
    {
        clmnGroupAssignments.getColumn().pack();
    }
});
tblvwrGroupAssignments.setContentProvider(new IStructuredContentProvider()
{
    public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput){}
    public void dispose(){}

    @Override
    public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement)
    {
        String[] toRet = ((String)inputElement).split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < toRet.length; i++)
        {
            toRet[i] = toRet[i].trim();
        }
        return toRet;
    }
});
tblvwrGroupAssignments.setUseHashlookup(true);
tblvwrGroupAssignments.setLabelProvider(new GroupAssignmentLabelProvider()); //responsible for displaying the last line italic
tblvwrGroupAssignments.setInput("HW_ADMIN, <Add new value here>");
```

The code above works just fine. The problem I have is about `EditingSupport`, to be precise about following method:

```
@Override
protected void setValue(Object element, Object value)
{
    element = value;
    viewer.update(element, null);
}
```

Usually I am supposed to cast `element` to the data type I used for the input and then invoke a setter. But since I work with `String`s which are immutable I can only replace old `String` with the new one. Apparently the `element` instance is not the same as an instance used by `TableViewer`, because the values in the table aren't being set.

Do I need to encapsulate `String` to some class or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to wrap the strings in a mutable object so that you can change the value to the new string.

All the uses of EditingSupport that I can see in the Eclipse source do this.